# Any formula for the exact number of primes below a given bound?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Reading  [The music of the primes](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Music-Primes-Unsolved-Mathematics/dp/1841155802), the author relates that Riemann had figured out a formula giving exact number of primes up to a certain bound with no errors.

Does such formula really exist? If yes, was it proven?

Comment: It is a sum, exact but not efficient for finding the value. See  http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417409.html

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: One might claim that the _real_ point is the precise _relation_ between primes and the zeros of zeta, as made clearer in Guinand's and Weil's extensions of Riemann's "Explicit formula", to be a sort of Fourier duality between the two. I find the _relation_ more interesting than either questions about counting primes, or any sort of "raw" version of questions about the zeros...